# R matrix correlation p value

Tags: r, correlation

We are measuring the groundwater-level at five different spots in an area.

**Null hypothesis**: the trend/progression of the groundwater-level of each spot is NOT different

**Alternative hypothese**: the trend/progression of the groundwater-level of each spot is different

We want to proove this statistically.

Below you can see part of the measurement data:

```
 > head(mydf)
      x1    x2   x3   x4   x5
1    -160  -76  -66  -29  -95
2    -159  -66  -63  -20  -85
3    -153  -63  -55  -19  -81
4    -156  -76  -54  -27  -83
5    -155  -75  -53  -30  -81
6    -145  -64  -49  -20  -71
```

Here is a [chart of the measurement data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i28Zp.png).

We did correlate the data:

```
> cor(mydf)
    x1         x2         x3         x4         x5
x1  1.0000000  0.8033349  0.8569253  0.8262110  0.8523034
x2  0.8033349  1.0000000  0.8228611  0.9036943  0.8965484
x3  0.8569253  0.8228611  1.0000000  0.8486466  0.9091440
x4  0.8262110  0.9036943  0.8486466  1.0000000  0.8828055
x5  0.8523034  0.8965484  0.9091440  0.8828055  1.0000000
```

We also tried to calculate the p-values using `rcorr(as.matrix(mydf))`, but received only a matrix of zeros.

We have several questions:

1. Why is the p value zero and how can we fix that?
2. Is our way of solving the problem wrong?
3. How can we extrapolate the given measurement data (see chart) in R?

Comment: I have voted to migrate this to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), since it seems to be more a question about statistics than about R code.

Comment: 1. Your obtained p-values are actually very small (like 0.0001) rather than zero or anything else. 2-3. You observe a multivariate time series with quite clean periodic/seasonal fluctuations, slightly increasing overall level, etc. That is, there is a lot what can be done and your approach is not good. You should look into the time series literature, particularly about trends, series decomposition, seasonality, etc. It will also lead you to a rich extrapolation literature.

Answer (score 1):

Guide for you to look at:

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-matrix-a-quick-start-guide-to-analyze-format-and-visualize-a-correlation-matrix-using-r-software

For interpretation of results and how to use, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to post.

With regards to your R questions:

The `rcorr()` function from the `Hmisc` package is pretty easy to use.

Example Data:

```
require(Hmisc)

set.seed(1)
x1 = rnorm(10,seed)
x2 = rnorm(10,seed)
x3 = x2 + rnorm(10,sd=.1,seed)
mydf <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
rcorr(as.matrix(mydf))
```

Gives an output of the Correlation Matrix as well as a pvalue matrix.  The guide above can help you flatten it and manipulate it for your needs.

```
      x1    x2    x3
x1  1.00 -0.38 -0.42
x2 -0.38  1.00  1.00
x3 -0.42  1.00  1.00

n= 10 


P
   x1     x2     x3    
x1        0.2833 0.2304
x2 0.2833        0.0000
x3 0.2304 0.0000
```

Comment: Thank you, but we already did all the stuff you told us (see first post). Our "problem" is/was, that there were only zeros shown, which might be an visual issue.